# How to get ruby file result in php page?

Tags: php, ruby

First of all i like to tell you,
that i don't know one word about Ruby.

But I have one ruby file which was downloaded from net.

But that file will give me some answers which i need on my php page.

So is there any way that, we can just pass the arguments to ruby file and then the script will  run and that output i can get back to my php page.

Or i have to convert that ruby file in php ( that also i don't know if its possible )

And How I will able to pass the values to ruby file and run that file on my server and get the result to my php page ?

Comment: which format does the ruby script output?

Comment: string...
if it possible then store in txt file, so after that i will get from that text file to php file.

Comment: that's simple then, just do as @sergio says.

Answer (score 3):

First, you'll have to install ruby. The easiest way, probably, is to use package manager of your OS to install "stock" ruby (in ubuntu this is something like `sudo apt-get install ruby`). However, the ruby community these days tends to use tools like [RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/) that allow you to easily install and use multiple rubies. For your case this is an overkill (IMHO).

Then, you'll have to install all gems (dependencies) that your ruby script requires. You can figure this out by reading the source. Normally, all dependencies will be on the top in the form of `require 'xxx'`. Normally, the name in `require` is the name of a gem. So, if you see `require 'nokogiri'`, you know you'll have to run `gem install 'nokogiri'`. If this doesn't work - then the required module is either bundled with ruby (e.g. ruby 1.9 bundles `rubygems` and `json`) or actual gem name differs. Google is your friend.

Then you can call this script from PHP. I believe you can use [`system()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) call for this.

Answer (score 0):

php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php
you could execute a command and gets the output but that requires to have installed ruby..
try to use json, or XML instead ruby files..